# access a specific input in an input array

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

[image]

```
<td><input type="text" name="product_code[]" id="product_code1" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
```

I have been creating an invoice system ... how can I access a specific input to get its text ( product code ) and load the description from the database???
I know how to access all the elements but cannot access the specific one the user is typing text :(

using the below code trying to get the value returns all the values of the product code text inputs and only works for the first one

```
       $('[name="product_code[]"]').keyup(function() {

        var values = $("input[name='product_code[]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

          alert(values);

    });
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`, `mysql` when the question is _"how to ... access the specific one the user is typing text"_ ?

Comment: You have to especify what you need, you cant access that input? you want to get its value?

Comment: ok my friend ... as i said accessing data from db so may be somebody else had the same problem as I do creating something similar so he/she can help ... thank you

Comment: Handle the input event of the textbox using JavaScript and send an AJAX request to the server to run some PHP which will query the data and return it.

Comment: still cant figure out what you want to do. You want to send it to DB or receive from DB and display it in the input?

Comment: Please add your attempt, the expected result of that attempt, example data and explain exactly where you're stuck. It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia lets say user types product code I want to access the db and retrieve product description for that product code ... how do I get through javascript or jquery the value of the specific input the user is typing???

Comment: @ADyson I know that but it gets all the values not the specific one

Comment: var product_codes = document.getElementsByName('product_code[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < product_codes.length; i++) {
                var product_code=product_codes[i];

Comment: i use the above to get all the values

Comment: how can I access a single value from the input text array so I can load the description ???

Comment: not just any single but the one the user is working on

Comment: @Lef You need something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/48uaoncw/

You can extend this example to call AJAX request and fill in description as per response.

Comment: `I know that`...then why haven't you used it? The code you've shown above in these comments has nothing to do with what I described. I wonder if you didn't actually get my point properly. The answer below explains in more detail what to do.

Comment: And regards the new code in the question, Instead if `var values = $("input[name='product_code[]']")` inside of the keyup, use this.value to get the value of the specific item which triggered the event.

Answer (score 2):

> @AlexisGarcia lets say user types product code I want to access the db and retrieve product description for that product code ... how do I get through javascript or jquery the value of the specific input the user is typing???

You have to use AJAX to get that from Database.
First you need to get what the user has typed (input value), and then send it to AJAX. Here is an example:

```js
$('#product_code1').keyup(function(){
  var user_text = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'link_to_your_controller',
        data: {text: user_text},
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(data) {
            
      //..DO SOMETHING WITH RESULT FROM DB
        
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="product_code[]" id="product_code1" class="form-    control input-sm" />
  </td>
```

You need to learn about AJAX to do what you need.
You can start by reading https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: already did like 7 times and cant figure out what you wan to do. If you want to get the text from the input, if you want to know how to do an ajax call. Cant understand nothing

Comment: IMO this answers the question exactly. Upvoted.

Comment: ok I am closing this question and submitting a better one ... I confused everybody ... sorry about that

Comment: @Lef why? You asked `how do I get through javascript or jquery the value of the specific input the user is typing?`...and that is exactly what `var user_text = $(this).val()` will do. So if that isn't what you really wanted, what is? And why did you ask it?

Comment: @ADyson  because that function loops through all the input elements of product_code and I do not know how to stop to the single one I want

Comment: @Lef `because that function loops through all the input elements of product_code`...no it doesn't. Have you actually tried it? It sets an event handler on all of them, yes. But then when you type in one of them, it triggers the event just on that one, and - as I've mentioned twice now - `this` will represent the one which was actually typed in, within the callback. I'm guessing you haven't worked with event handlers before very much?

Comment: @AlexisGarcia I have just noticed a slight flaw in your example though...your selector for the keyup event is wrong - it would only attach the handler to one element, using an ID. Lef made clear that there are in fact multiple textboxes which need this event handler. You should use the selector they originally showed in the code in the question. But the use of `$(this).val()` is correct and is the key to what Lef needs.

Comment: like i said in the answer its just an example so he can figure out on how to do what he needs. He can adjust the selectors, ajax content and link and etc.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia well he can't though can he, otherwise he'd have used your example instead of saying it's no good. And it's always better to provide a specific solution to the problem in the question, not just a generic example - because often the OP does not have sufficient understanding to swap things in and out, you need to give the specific answer and then explain what it does. And it's not exactly any effort to change it, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.input-sm').keyup(function() {

    var values = $(this).val();

      alert(values);

});
```

Try this code, you will get what you want